# permutation word problem altered photographs with paintings

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations, computational-mathematics

A photographer and a painter decide to make an exhibition and they agree to present 5 photographs and 4 paintings respectively. With how many ways can the exhibition be done if the photographer has in his possession 9 photographs and the painter 8 paintings and the photographs - paintings are placed together alternately in a row;

I did 5!4!(9P4)(8P4) is this correct?

Comment: This isn't quite right, be sure to note the difference between permutations and combinations. Also, note that they are presenting 5 photos and not 4.

Comment: 5!4!(9C5)(8C4)?

Comment: That looks right! You could also do 9P5 * 8P4, but your new answer represents the exact same thing.